# How to get the values of child nodes of multiple identical nodes of XML with Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<injuryRespData>
  <lc01s>
    <lc01>
      <aac001>1</aac001>
      <alca02>2</alca02>
      <aab001>3</aab001>
    </lc01>
    <lc01>
      <aac001>4</aac001>
      <alca02>5</alca02>
      <aab001>6</aab001>
    </lc01>
    <lc01>
      <aac001>7</aac001>
      <alca02>8</alca02>
      <aab001>9</aab001>
    </lc01>
  </lc01s>
</injuryRespData>
```

I have a Class and List entity:

```
public class lc01
{
   public string aac001{set;get;}
   public string alca02{set;get;}
   public string aab001{set;get;}
}
List<lc01> list = new List<lc01>();
```

How could I get the values of child nodes under multiple `lc01` nodes respectively and add to the List collection using Linq to XML?

Comment: Use `XmlSerializer` you already have a class which represents data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself：

```
var xml = @"<injuryRespData>
    <lc01s>
    <lc01>
        <aac001>1</aac001>
        <alca02>2</alca02>
        <aab001>3</aab001>
    </lc01>
    <lc01>
        <aac001>4</aac001>
        <alca02>5</alca02>
        <aab001>6</aab001>
    </lc01>
    <lc01>
        <aac001>7</aac001>
        <alca02>8</alca02>
        <aab001>9</aab001>
    </lc01>
    </lc01s>
</injuryRespData>";

XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
List<lc01> lc01List =  new List<lc01>();
lc01List.clear();
foreach (XElement item in RespDoc.Descendants("lc01"))
{
   lc01 temp = lc01()
   {
      aac001 = item.Element("aac001").Value,
      alca02 = item.Element("alca02").Value,
      aab001 = item.Element("aab001").Value
   }
   lc01List.Add(lc01);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using [`Descendants`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) methods:

```
List<lc01> list=doc.Root.Descendants("lc01")
                   .Select(e=>new lc01{aac001=(string)e.Element("aac001"),
                                       alca02=(string)e.Element("alca02"),
                                       aab001=(string)e.Element("aab001")
                                      })
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = @"<injuryRespData>
    <lc01s>
    <lc01>
        <aac001>1</aac001>
        <alca02>2</alca02>
        <aab001>3</aab001>
    </lc01>
    <lc01>
        <aac001>4</aac001>
        <alca02>5</alca02>
        <aab001>6</aab001>
    </lc01>
    <lc01>
        <aac001>7</aac001>
        <alca02>8</alca02>
        <aab001>9</aab001>
    </lc01>
    </lc01s>
</injuryRespData>";

var result = (
    from x in XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("lc01").Cast<XElement>()
    select new XmlSerializer(typeof(lc01)).Deserialize(new StringReader(x.ToString()))).ToList();
```